# jQuery like Linq?

Tags: javascript, jquery, linq

My googling skills are failing me.

My understanding is that there is a way that I can start writing jQuery in a way that makes it very similar to Linq. I don't necessarily mean in syntax but more in definition (using inline/anonymous functions). However, I'm failing to understand how to take it there.

So to help me, I've created a page with a TextArea and I want the TextArea to increase in height (i.e. `rows=10` or whatever) as I insert newlines in them. So I'd like to do this with the following script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(#mytxt).keypress(function () {
                $(this).attr(rows, $(this).val().select(function (x) { x == '\n'}).count());
            });
        });
</script>
```

So how can I do this where I continue to do this in a Linq-esque way? Note that I know I can do this in many other ways within javascript (regex, splitting a string on a delimiter, etc.) but I want to do this in a Linq-like way. Also, I don't want to use any [third-party libraries/plugins](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/) to help with this - I'm looking for something that is standard in jQuery. Again, exact syntax is not what I want to be like Linq (even though that's kinda how I wrote my example) - just the concept.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking for. Those functions are about as anonymous as possible using javascript.

Comment: I want to figure out what to replace `$(this).val().select(function (x) { x == '\n'}).count()` with to make this work. That jQuery code does not work but I believe it's close to working to count the number of newLines in the `mytxt` textarea's text.

Comment: I think your thinking is in the lamdas space that both lanaguages use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are somehow correct.
LINQ operates with IQueryable type, while jQuery operates with a jQuery :). Though IQueryable is much more abstract than jQuery object, in terms of data.
You misunderstood, however, the concept of what data is there which is non-jQuery. The jQuery object revolves around DOM objects, and only operates with them. Values may be passed and tossed around, but there has to be DOM, or jQuery is pointless. To compare, IQueryable was made to work with data, with values, or with objects. These are 2 totally different concepts, which only have some similar  principle when working with them.

- `$(#mytxt)` should be `$("#mytxt")`
- `val()` returns a scalar, which is not jQuery, so you can't apply an event handler using `select()`
- `$(document).ready(callback)` syntax is kind of deprecated, use `jQuery(callback)` instead, or just `$(callback)`
- I would advise you check the event, to see what key was pressed, so as not to resize the DOM element each time a key is pressed. You can pass an argument, i.e. `event` to the callback function, which will receive data about the event. `event.which` would be the character code. For more info, visit [this page](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

as a result, you would have something like this as an option:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#mytxt").keypress(function (event) {
            if(event.which==13)
                $(this).attr("rows", $(this).val().split("\n").length );
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note that `val()` returns a scalar (a generic JavaScript string), which has nothing to do with jQuery from here on. `split()` is a JavaScript function for string manipulation, so is `length` a JavaScript attribute for measuring array length.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. And thanks for correcting my errors (which Alex also did).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(function() {

    $('#mytxt').keypress(function (e) {

        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if(code == 13) { //Only do this when enter is pressed

            $(this).attr('rows', function() {
                var val = $(this).val();
                return val.split('\n').length;
            });

         }

    });
});
```

Comment: Closer. Having that inside function return a value is part of what I was missing. Now how do I take a string and iterate over each character and pass that character in as a parameter to a function that returns a boolean, which would be the equivalent to a lambda expression passed into a Linq `.Select` method?

Comment: @Jaxidian, jQuery was made mainly for DOM manipulation. It does not work with values, it is centered around DOM. For string manipulation, and other stuff, there are other libraries, but not jQuery.